# How to unlock SQL Server 2008 table in ADO.NET/C# 4.0 using SqlClient?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, sqlclient

I created a method while back that:

1. Locked a table
2. Read value from it
3. Wrote updated value back
4. Unlocked the table

The code worked for Oracle. Now I can't get it work for SQL Server 2008. The method is below and executing my unlocking command results in a `SqlException` with text:

> *"NOLOC" is not a recognized table hints option. If it is intended as a
>   parameter to a table-valued function or to the CHANGETABLE function,
>   ensure that your database compatibility mode is set to 90.*

Code:

```
public static int GetAndSetMaxIdTable(DbProviderFactory factory, DbConnection cnctn, DbTransaction txn, int tableId, string userName, int numberOfIds)
{
        bool isLocked = false;
        string sql = string.Empty;
        string maxIdTableName;

        if (tableId == 0)
            maxIdTableName = "IdMax";
        else
            maxIdTableName = "IdMaxTable";

        try
        {
            bool noPrevRow = false;
            int realMaxId;

            if (factory is OracleClientFactory)
                sql = string.Format("lock table {0} in exclusive mode", maxIdTableName);
            else if (factory is SqlClientFactory)
                sql = string.Format("select * from {0} with (TABLOCKX)", maxIdTableName);
            else
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Unsupported DbProviderFactory -type: {0}", factory.GetType().ToString()));

            using (DbCommand lockCmd = cnctn.CreateCommand())
            {
                lockCmd.CommandText = sql;
                lockCmd.Transaction = txn;
                lockCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                isLocked = true;
            }

            using (DbCommand getCmd = cnctn.CreateCommand())
            {
                getCmd.CommandText = CreateSelectCommand(factory, tableId, userName, getCmd, txn);

                object o = getCmd.ExecuteScalar();
                if (o == null)
                {
                    noPrevRow = true;
                    realMaxId = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    realMaxId = Convert.ToInt32(o);
                }
            }

            using (DbCommand setCmd = cnctn.CreateCommand())
            {
                if (noPrevRow)
                    setCmd.CommandText = CreateInsertCommand(factory, tableId, userName, numberOfIds, realMaxId, setCmd, txn);
                else
                    setCmd.CommandText = CreateUpdateCommand(factory, tableId, userName, numberOfIds, realMaxId, setCmd, txn);

                setCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            if (factory is OracleClientFactory)
                sql = string.Format("lock table {0} in share mode", maxIdTableName);
            else if (factory is SqlClientFactory)
                sql = string.Format("select * from {0} with (NOLOC)", maxIdTableName);             

            using (DbCommand lockCmd = cnctn.CreateCommand())
            {
                lockCmd.CommandText = sql;
                lockCmd.Transaction = txn;
                lockCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                isLocked = false;
            }

            return realMaxId;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          ...
        }
}
```

So what goes wrong here? Where does this error come from? Server or client? I copied the statement from C code and it's supposed to work there. Unfortunately I can't debug and check if it works for me.

Edit: Just trying to lock and unlock (without reading or updating) results in same exception.

Thanks & BR -Matti

Comment: Well it's NOLOCK for one thing. Do you actually want to lock every other potential process out of the entire table? The usual way to do something like this would be in a transaction, and it would work on Oracle and SQL Server. If you want down that route you wouldn't need Oracle or SQL Server Specific Sql, and with IDbConnection, IDbCommand etc, you could get rid of most of the if Oracle stuff and get much close to being provider agnostic

Comment: Thanks 4 ur answer Tony. Yes every client that tries to access the table must be locked out. I would like to get this work 1st, but i'm open to more sophisticated approaches as well. If u don't know why I get this exception u can post an example how to do this with transaction. Actually I'm already using a transaction here, but appararently the approach u suggested is smthn else.

Comment: That is going to be one slow application if you always lock the whole table.

Comment: @horse: instead of dissing can u provide some _concrete_ alternatives? the other table has only 1 row and other maybe 30. both have 3 columns. besides the ids are fetched very rarely. has no effect to overall performance whatsoever.

Comment: One record? Tell us more, a better solution might be not to use a table at all. A singleton to manage access to the resource seems to have potential.

Comment: @tony: this is a table that dozens of different applications coded with various languages (desktop, batch programs, windows services, web services) use. there can be hundreds of instances that want ids, running on multitude of systems. of course now there could be e.g. WS that gives ids to all different applications but it's done like this back inna day.

Comment: Then even if you came up with a new mechanism, actually implementing it across all those disparate systems is going to be a step too far, well several steps probably. Looks like it's one of those legacy features you either live with, or start engineering out. Getting buy in for the latter, when a few lines of clever code will fix it would be nigh on impossible.

Comment: that's true. exactly why i'm asking _this_ question. the reason why i'm interested in other mechanisms is that it's nice to hear ideas from other developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TABLOCKX hint locks the table as you intend, but you can't unlock it manually. How long the lock stays on depends on your transaction level. If you don't have an active transaction on your connection, the lock is held while the SELECT executes and is discarded thereafter.

If you want to realize the sequence "lock the table -> do something with the table -> release the lock" you would need to implement the ADO.NET equivalent of this T-SQL script:

```
BEGIN TRAN
    SELECT TOP (1) 1 FROM myTable (TABLOCKX, KEEPLOCK)
    -- do something with the table
COMMIT -- This will release the lock, if there is no outer transaction present
```

you can either execute the "BEGIN TRAN"/"COMMIT" through DbCommand objects or you can use the System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction class to start a transaction and commit it.

Attention: This approach only works if your connection is not enlisted in a transaction already! SQL Server doesn't support nested transaction, so the COMMIT wouldn't do anything and the lock would be held. If you have a transaction already running, you cannot release the lock until the transaction finishes. In this case maybe a synchronisation through sp_getapplock/sp_releaseapplock might help.

Edit: If you want to educate yourself about transactions, locking and blocking, I recommend these two videos: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/gg545007.aspx and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/gg508892.aspx

Comment: That's sneaky, can't say I would gave thought of that, but I'd be trying to engineer out the need for an exclusive lock any way.

Comment: @TToni: Thanks for your answer! I try tomorrow at work to just drop the "unlock" part and commit/rollback the DbTransaction. Good to know this limitation, since it is one. Thanks for adding it here so I don't have to wonder what goes wrong. I accept this when I'm able to try it. Thanks again!

Comment: @Tony: I think you are absolutely right. I'm actually imitating legacy C-code here which is always bad idea. I'd love to hear how would u do this. My knowledge about SQL Server and "inherent locking" in DBs in general is zero. By inherent locking I mean what happens when I open cursor/begin transaction and close/end them (if any kind of locking even happen in such or other cases).

Comment: I'll post an alternative, give me a mo

Comment: I restricted myself to the immediate locking problem, but of course in general you should try to avoid excessive locking. An exclusive table lock is very seldom really necessary. I could elaborate more with two bits of information: What kind of "bad" behaviour do you want to prevent with the locking and since you seem to have an outer transaction, what serialization level is it running on. Oh, and is ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION or READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT in the database set to ON? All these things influence SQL Server locking behavior in a transaction (see videos in the answer).

Comment: thanks TToni! that restriction was exactly what i wanted. what is tried to achieve is to prevent different clients (this can mean dozens of different programs) to get duplicate ids. there can be as many as hundreds of clients running on same time. but they get ids quite seldomly so it's not a big issue that it's locked once in a while for a moment. at the moment this piece of code is not used by many programs so _IF_ there's outer transaction i can get rid of it by getting ids 1st.

Comment: continued: I know nothing about ser. level or the settings. I'm sorry that I can't now use enough time for this. I think the solution should be quite universal and not depending on settings.

Comment: The "correct" way to generate sequential identity values in SQL Server without locking issues is the use of identity columns. Don't know if that works for you, but in that case look here: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/understanding-identity-columns

Comment: actually what i'm currently doing is not nested transactions. so there is not outer transaction with the connection ever. what i am doing is that both getting the ids and inserting new items to tables with these new ids are in same transaction. this way if something goes wrong i don't lose ids or try to insert them with temporary/fake ids.

Comment: @TToni: Thanks again, I accepted it before trying cause i'm really busy at the work. This KEEPLOCK resulted in exception and wasn't needed at all. That's why I put my onw answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer for one table for SqlClient with code I made based on TToni's answer:

```
    public static int GetAndSetMaxIdTable(DbProviderFactory factory, DbConnection cnctn,   DbTransaction txn, int numberOfIds)
    {
            bool noPrevRow = false;
            int realMaxId;


            using (DbCommand getCmd = cnctn.CreateCommand())
            {
                getCmd.CommandText = "SELECT MaxId FROM IdMax WITH (TABLOCKX)"
                getCmd.Transaction = txn;

                object o = getCmd.ExecuteScalar();
                if (o == null)
                {
                    noPrevRow = true;
                    realMaxId = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    realMaxId = Convert.ToInt32(o);
                }
            }

            using (DbCommand setCmd = cnctn.CreateCommand())
            {
                if (noPrevRow)
                    setCmd.CommandText = CreateInsertCommand(factory, tableId, userName, numberOfIds, realMaxId, setCmd, txn);
                else
                    setCmd.CommandText = CreateUpdateCommand(factory, tableId, userName, numberOfIds, realMaxId, setCmd, txn);

                setCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            return realMaxId;
    }
```

and it i's like this:

```
        ...

        try
        {
            using (txn = cnctn.BeginTransaction())
            {
                oldMaxId = GetAndSetMaxIdTable(factory, cnctn, txn, 5);
                for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    UseNewIdToInsertStuff(factory, cnctn, txn, oldMaxId + i + 1)
                }
                txn.Commit();
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // don't know if this is needed
            if (txn != null && cnctn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                txn.Rollback();

            throw e;
        }

        ...
```

For oracle client it seems to be desirable to have:

```
SELECT MaxId from IdMax WHERE ... FOR UPDATE OF MaxId
```

-m